# Changing input array name with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I've some fields that use an array as name like this :

```
<select name="attr[address][#ID]">
<textarea name="address[#ID][cp]" placeholder="CP"></textarea>
```

I would like to change the therm "#ID" of all the fields with an unqiue ID using jQuery, is it possible to use something like regex with the .attr() function in order to change the #ID ?

Regards,
Adrien

Comment: What do you have? What do you wanna do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace all occurrences of `#ID` in a name attribute with a monotomically increasing number like this:

```
var cntr = 1;
$("[name*='#ID']").each(function() {
    this.name = this.name.replace(/#ID/, cntr++);
});
```

Comment: +1, you could also pass the `index` to the `each` function, that way there's no need for the `cntr`

Comment: @deifwud - yes, it could be done that way.  This way allows you to establish whatever baseline you want and/or use the cntr over time to generate other unique IDs.  Either is fine.